# Detecting a click on a tile

Tags: collision-detection, tiles, input, lwjgl, mouse

I'm making a simple tile-map system in LWJGL, and I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the mouse is clicking inside of a tile. So far no matter where I click it's always the same tile that is shown.

Code:

```
int blockWidth = 100;
int blockHeight = 100;

List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

private void addTiles(){
    for(int i = 0; i < ((Display.getHeight() / blockHeight) * (Display.getWidth() / blockWidth)); i++)
        tiles.add(new Tile(10,10,blockWidth,blockHeight, i));
}

//...

if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
            System.out.println("Mouse clicked at (" + Mouse.getX() + ", " + Mouse.getY() + ")");
            for(Tile tile : tiles){
                if(tile.inBounds(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY())){
                    tile.highlight();
                    System.out.println("Box clicked at (" + Mouse.getX() + ", " + Mouse.getY() + ").");
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

the inBounds method:

```
public boolean inBounds(int x, int y){
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    if(bounds.intersects(x,y,1,1)){
        System.out.println("Tile " + num + " clicked. X/Y val is (" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` and `y` you use here:

```
bounds.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

are the parameters `x`, `y` that are being passed into the method.

I am assuming that there is also an `x` and `y` in your Tile class. So you either need to rename the parameters or use `this.` in front of your variables.

```
public boolean inBounds(int x, int y){
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.setBounds(this.x, this.y, width, height); // change here
    if(bounds.intersects(x,y,1,1)){
        System.out.println("Tile " + num + " clicked. X/Y val is (" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "this" is very tricky! A very common mistake. One that I am prone to as well even after as many years as I have been coding. The primary way I use to combat this problem (usually quite effectively), is to always have "the" in front of parameters passed to a function. For example, if I were to write inBounds, the parameter names would be theX and theY.  Helps me anyway. Might help others as well to have a naming convention to help avoid this all too common issue.

Comment: @PlayDeezGames - I've gotten into the habit of naming all my class [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) starting with an underscore (`_`). I've also seen the use of `m_` for fields (the "m" stands for "member" because, as you can see in the docs, fields implement the `Member` interface). Personally, I don't really like the `m_` but regardless, naming and scope are very important when programming. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the potentially O(N*M) containemt checks by simply calculating the tile's array index in O(1) time:

```
int pixelCoordToIndex(int x, int y)
{
    return ((y / tileHeight) * numTilesX) + (x / tileWidth);
}
```

Your code is then reduced to:

```
System.out.println("Tile " + pixelCoordToIndex(x, y) + " clicked. X/Y val is (" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

This decouples the performance of containment checks from the map's extents, saving millions of unnecessary checks on moderately large maps.